# Getting error LNK2019 when attempting to compile OpenCV program with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I have followed [this](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.no/2013/05/installing-configuring-opencv-with-vs.html) tutorial for setting up OpenCV and I'm attempting to compile the example program with Visual Studio 2012. But I get the following error message:

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gzputs referenced in function "void __cdecl icvPuts(struct CvFileStorage *,char const *)" (?icvPuts@@YAXPAUCvFileStorage@@PBD@Z)   c:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\NewProject\NewProject\opencv_core246d.lib(persistence.obj)  NewProject`

I suspect that something isn't being linked correctly, but other than that I'm pretty confused.

Comment: -1 For doing not enough research. +1 For doing your job after asking.

Comment: @Zaibis It's a zero-sum game then. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the problem pretty quickly. I am using a 64-bit system, but I had included the x86 libraries instead of the 64-bit ones. All I had to do was change the libraries to the correct folders.

[image]